# How to call a javascript from plugin or refresh the page in microsoft dynamics 2015

Tags: javascript, plugins, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015, xrm

We have a requirement in which we have to call a Javascript from plugin,
also we want to refresh our page from plugin. 
Is there any way to do this? We know this can be done from javascript using XRM but we need to refresh our page after plugin execution so for the same we will need a call to javascript from plugin or any other way to refresh our page from plgin.

We cannot make our plugin as synchronous.

Comment: Hi Karmal, there is no way from an asynch plugin to refresh the form (imagine if 200 users have the same form that need to be refreshed open). The closest thing is to execute an asynch js function and refresh the page on the callback

Answer (score 3):

One solution could be to set an attribute on the regarding entity in the plugin execution that indicates, that the process finished.Then let a javascript run, which checks this attribute periodically and performs the refresh.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to override the Save button's default functionality and call you custom code (js function) when user clicks the save button.

```
function customSave()
{
     Xrm.Page.data.save().then(
       function(){
          Xrm.Utility.alertDialog("Record saved");
          Xrm.Page.data.refresh();
         },
       function(error){
          Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(error.message);
     });
}
```

**Correction:** I just saw you have mentioned that your plugin will run ASync... This solution will not work.